# How to swap postion of two keys+values in a list of dictionaries json using python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, swap

I have a json file with thousands of documents, these are nested documents, where i need to swap the position in the list of two key-value pairs. Each document is like this:

```
{'DataColeta': '2019-01-02',
'GrupoProduto': 'Etanol',
'Produto': 'ETANOL HIDRATADO COMUM',
'Posto': {'razaosocial': 'POSTO DE GASOLINA N S DA PENHA LTDA',
'CNPJ': '33.267.816/0001-35',
'Distribuidora': 'IPIRANGA PRODUTOS DE PETRÓLEO S.A',
'endereco': 'AVENIDA BRAZ DE PINA,253',
'complemento': '',
'bairro': 'PENHA',
'Latitude': -22.84026333,
'Longitude': -43.281765},
'Ensaios': {'Cor': {'Resultado': 'Incolor', 'Unidade': '', 'Conforme':        'Sim'},
'Aspecto': {'Resultado': 'Límpido e isento de impurezas (LII)',
'Unidade': '',
'Conforme': 'Sim'},
'Condutividade Elétrica': {'Resultado': '97',
'Unidade': 'µS/m',
'Conforme': 'Sim'},
'Massa Específica a 20°C': {'Resultado': '809.8',
'Unidade': 'kg/m³',
'Conforme': 'Sim'},
'Teor Alcoólico': {'Resultado': '93.0',
'Unidade': '% massa',
'Conforme': 'Sim'},
'Potencial Hidrogeniônico (pH)': {'Resultado': '6.8',
'Unidade': '',
'Conforme': 'Sim'},
'Teor de Hidrocarbonetos': {'Resultado': 'Não detectado',
'Unidade': '',
'Conforme': 'Sim'}},
'UF': 'RJ',
'municipio': 'RIO DE JANEIRO',
'id_amostra': '463328'}
```

The key-value pairs I want to swap position is the Longitude and Latitude, so I can do a Geospatial query in MongoDB. It should come with Longitude before Latitude on the list.

The json file is called : "amostras"

The embedded field I want to change is "Posto" and I tried to do this:
'''python
    amostras[i]["Posto"].keys()

```
dict_keys(['razaosocial', 'CNPJ', 'Distribuidora', 'endereco',               'complemento', 'bairro', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])


def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2): 

    list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1] 
    return list

List = list(amostras[i]["Posto"].keys())
pos1, pos2 = 6, 7
for i in range(len(amostras)):
    swapPositions(List, pos1+1, pos2-1)
```

'''

But it always give me an error:

'dict_keys' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

After 3.6 version of Python dict key-value pairs order by insertion. So if you rewrite your function as:

```
def order_geodata(doc):
    latitude, longitude = doc['Latitude'], doc['Longitude']
    del doc['Latitude']
    del doc['Longitude']
    doc['Longitude'] = longitude
    doc['Latitude'] = latitude
```

It will place geodata params in your desired order at the end of dict used as order_geodata() target.

Be sure that all target jsons will have both 'Longitude' and 'Latitude' keys. Otherwise you'll need to change direct dict indexing to dict.get('key') form to prevent errors in cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nornil, unfortunately I can not upvote you as my reputation is still too low.